# No headers or footers on new Joomla 2.5 articles

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have added new articles in Joomla 2.5. Then I add a new menu item to link to a single article. The link works ok but when I see the article page it only has the contents of the article, no header and footer from my previous page.

Anything I have found on the net has only told me how to add new articles, and I cannot find a solution to the problem of not seeing anything but the articles.

Any help would be great.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to check: Extensions -> Module Manager -> (click at the modules that you want to display) -> Menu Assignment -> On all pages.

Comment: YesI have that done already and its still not working.

Comment: Does your url contain "&tmpl=component"?

Comment: Please try also to clear your joomla cache.

Comment: No URL does not contain that  URL is:  .com/index.php/georgian-range Also  cleared cache still nothing.

Comment: Are you sure that modules added to a module position of your active template?

Comment: Oh thank you. It's always something simple.